# Show AWS files in google doc viewer

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, documentviewer

I have my document placed in AWS bucket which are private by default as per my requirement.I want to show these files with any viewer (currently i am using google doc viewer) but mostly the document viewer accepts simple url instead of any key .

I have tried with Assess Control List, but in this case we are having issue with the url as that will contain some access key.

So can anyone please suggest on viewing the files on online document viewer with private AWS bucket files.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a locally hosted file viewing page that contains your credentials on your server and just have the page show the file to them like that, depending on the document type.

Comment: I am using heroku as hosting provider and heroku dyno clear additional file (added later and not part of build) so we cannot rely on heroku for this case.